# Core Image getting sample buffer from video on disk?

Tags: ios, core-image

So when recording live video, you can use an AVCaptureSession and filter live video through the delegate method:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

Using that, you can get a CIImage from the buffer which you can later apply an image filter to:

```
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CIImage *sourceImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)imageBuffer options:nil];
```

My question is, how can I filter a video from disk? Since I don't have the luxury of that delegate method to give me output buffers automatically, I'll have to do it manually.

What I need is a way to get frame by frame from a video on disk and apply a Core Image filter to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this [AVCaptureSession_Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

There is a lot of samples and for me `"SquareCam"` and 
`"StopNGo for iOS"` was enough.

It will give you frame by frame in memory, but not on disk. If you need it - you could do it by yourself.